# Controller for has_many :thorugh association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models (Users and Cursos), where a user can join multiples cursos and a curso can have multiple users, so I used a has_many :through association between them with a model called Inscripciones (only stores the user_id and curso_id).

Now I'm trying to figure out how to allow the current user join an existing curso from the index view of cursos, but I don't know if I should do this through the Inscripciones controller or what.

Also, if it has to be done through the Inscripciones controller, I can't figure out how to create this new association in the controller and also how to do it without rendering a new view (as it has no need to display a form).

Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve this:

```
current_user.cursos << @curso
```

Comment: As a non-Ajax request? Make a new route in the `Cursos` controller, map it in `routes.rb`, and submit to it.

Comment: Have you tried `current_user.cursos.new`? You should find that Rails 'just works' and created the intervening Inscripciones record for you automatically.